# How to animate view from top to bottom?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app I want to launch UIViewController from top to bottom.So from FirstViewController I am launching MyWebViewController(which I need to animate) as follows:

```
MyWebViewController *theWebViewController = [[MyWebViewController alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:theWebViewController.view];
```

and In loadView of MyWebViewController I am assigning frame to view as follows;

```
- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect theFrame;
    theFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, mFrame.size.width, 0.0);
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.frame = theFrame;
    self.view = view;
    [view release];
}
```

and In viewDidLoad I am changing the frame as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateView" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 20.0, mFrame.size.width, mFrame.size.height-20.0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

But the animation is not happening.I even tried this code to animate from bottom to top and it is working fine but vice-versa not working.Please can anyone tell me where I am doing wrong and how I can achieve?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to present a view controller "modally" so that it slides up from the bottom and covers the entire screen? The user then presses a "Done" button and dismisses the view controller and it returns to FirstViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't think to set the height to 0. Instead:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    CGRect theFrame;
    theFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, -mframe.size.height + 20, mFrame.size.width, m.frame.size.height - 20);
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
    view.frame = theFrame;
    self.view = view;
    [view release];
}
```

You want to set the frame above and out of the view when you add it. Then move it into place in the animation.